# How to change the default command for remote-ssh in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I found this in my log when I was trying to set connection in remote ssh. But it didn't work because of the option "-T",
In other words it works if I use "ssh -v -D 62505 -o ConnectTimeout=30 xxx". How can I fix it?

```
[11:49:48.866] Spawned 13230
[11:49:49.000] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: "-v -T -D 62505 -o ConnectTimeout=30 xxx"
[11:49:49.003] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=13235
```

I just tried some settings but didn't work

Comment: what if you create an issue at the SSH remote extension

Comment: if you or anyone else creates an issue ticket, please ping me with a link to it either here (@starball), or in the issue ticket (@starball5)